# Reading a kinect depth file in C++

Tags: c++, file, computer-vision, kinect

To read the depth data of a frame, the first 28 bytes of the depth file have to be skipped and the rest is an array of 320*240 unsigned shorts i.e. 320*240*2 bytes (because each depth frame has 320 x 240 pixels). I have included my code for reading the depth file, however it always hangs when I try to run it. Please let me know how to correct the code.

```
int main()
{
    int array_size = 76800*2;
    char *data[array_size];
    unsigned short depth[320][240];
    int i,j;
    // open the depth file in read mode.
    ifstream infile("000000.depth");
    // check for error in opening file
    if(!infile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout<< "File could not be opened";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Reading from the file" << endl;
    infile.seekg(29,ios::beg); // discarding first 28 bytes

    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        infile >> data[array_size];
    }
    // storing data in required array
    for (i=0; i = 320; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j=240; j++)
        {
            depth[i][j] = (unsigned short)atof(data[i*j]);
            std::cout << depth[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Reading with `while(eof)` is wrong, not opening the file in binary mode, for loops use assignment instead of comparison, and you allocate space for `char*` instead of space for `char`.

Comment: I would be great, if you provide example of `000000.depth` file's contents (the first 60 bytes, just to see the format)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your file can be not text file, so try to open file in binary mode, i.e. change

```
 ifstream infile("000000.depth");
```

to

```
 ifstream infile("000000.depth", std::ios::binary);
```

and use `infile.read()` instead of `infile >>` to read data.

**EDIT:**

Also I have a question: Reading data to array `data` that looks like

```
while(!infile.eof())
{
    infile >> data[array_size];
}
```

should read elements of `char` type or `char *` (C-style strings)?

Check type of `data` in declaration (I guess it must be `char data[array_size];`) and consider reading from file as

```
 infile.get (data,array_size);
```

**EDIT 2:**

As user3589654 and Vincent Fourmond said you have wrong conditions in loops `for`, but also conversion

```
 depth[i][j] = (unsigned short)atof(data[i*j]);
```

is potential source of problems:

1) `atof` converts to `float` but not to `int` nor `unsigned short`

2) expression `data[i*j]` will take data from wrong parts of memory, I think you want `data[i*240 + j]` (or something like that)

3) if your file is not text file where numbers is stored as space-separated ASCII symbol sequences, such approaches for reading and conversion are absolutely inappropriate

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is where you allocating `char * data[array_size]`, try `char data[array_size]` because you are allocating array_size of pointers not block of memory. Also your for loop should be

```
for(i=0;i<320;i++)
  for(j=0;j<320;j++)
   { 
        //do your stuff here

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, you seem to have problems with `for` loops. Looking at:

```
 for (i=0; i = 320; i++)
```

This means "run the loop, with `i` starting from 0, for as long as `i = 320` is true". The thing is that `i = 320` evaluates as `320` as a value, which is always true. You wanted `i < 320`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your inputs. I have completely changed my code and it is now working. I wrote it in C instead of C++.

The basic error was in the for loops as mentioned. The while loop was also a source of error, and it was unnecessary to first read it in char and then convert it to unsigned short. The new code is mentioned below;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
unsigned short depth[320][240],x;
int i,j;

FILE *infile = fopen("000000.depth","rb");
fseek(infile, 29, SEEK_SET);
printf("Reading data from depth file");

for (i=0; i < 320; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<240; j++)
{
        fread(&x, sizeof x, 1, infile);
        depth[i][j] = x;
        printf("\n%d %d",depth[i][j],x);
}
}

fclose(infile);
getch();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: I'd also switch the dimensions: depth[240][320], i<240, j<320, etc... or else you'll end up with weird stuff when trying to draw the image. Unless the image was saved this way too which by the looks of his code, doesn't seem so.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I have already switched the dimensions. How did you know that they have to be switched though?

Comment: It's the usual method of storing/reading images: it's very, very rare to see it stored the other way around. So, you could say it was a lucky guess :)